# Warning 'atomic' attribute on property 'previewItemURL' does not match the property inherited from 'QLPreviewItem'

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, properties, protocols

I have a class

```
@interface ATPreviewItem : NSObject <QLPreviewItem> 

@property(atomic, strong) NSURL * previewItemURL; 
@property(atomic, strong) NSString * previewItemTitle;

@end
```

The QLPreviewItem protocol has property

```
@property(readonly, nonnull, nonatomic) NSURL * previewItemURL;
@property(readonly, nullable, nonatomic) NSString * previewItemTitle;
```

I am getting warning as:

> 'atomic' attribute on property 'previewItemURL' does not match the property inherited from 'QLPreviewItem'

So what is correct way of declaring property without warning with overriding property attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare those properties in `ATPreviewItem` as you will inherit them from the `QLPreviewItem` protocol.

So the best way is to remove the declarations.

Comment: How can I change the property attributes to atomic and strong?

Comment: @PK86 I don't believe you're supposed to override the attributes of a property from a super class (or protocol, in this case).  It's already `strong`, so it's just the `atomic` that's the issue (a small one IMO).  One possibility is to override the setter/getter in the implementation.  I haven't tested that, however.  BTW your question never mentions you want to intentionally change the attributes.